# Having test spec name as test name in browserstack

Tags: protractor, browserstack

I want to set the test spec name as the test name in browserstack. Below is my browserstack stack config file. I am using protractor.

```
 exports.makeDefaultCapabilities = function(that) {
  return {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      prefs: {
        credentials_enable_service: false,
      args: [
        'disable-infobars=true',
      ]
    },
    loggingPrefs: {
      driver: 'WARNING',
      server: 'WARNING',
      browser: 'INFO'
    },
    'browserstack.user': 'xx'
    'browserstack.key': 'xxx',
    'browserstack.debug': true,
  };
};

exports.config = {

  suites: {
    smoke: [
      '*/*.js'
    ]
  },

  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  baseUrl: undefined,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  allScriptsTimeout: 100000,
  getPageTimeout: 100000,
  maxSessions: 1,
  seleniumAddress: 'https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

  getMultiCapabilities: function() {
    let that = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      let defaults = exports.makeDefaultCapabilities(that);

      let capabilities = [];


      capabilities.push({
        os: 'OS X',
        os_version: 'High Sierra'
      });

      _.forEach(capabilities, function(capability) {
        _.defaultsDeep(capability, defaults);
      });

      resolve(capabilities);
    });
  },

  beforeSession: function(config, capabilities, specs) {
    capabilities.name = specs && specs[0].split('/').pop() || undefined;
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
    let reporter = new SpecReporter();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  }
};
```

The beforeSession hook doesn't update the test name in browserstack as the test spec name. 
Looking forward for any suggestion. Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include `const request = require('request');` in the *.conf.js file and following snippet in onPrepare() function. This will get the name of your test spec and change the name using BrowserStack REST API.

```
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specStarted: function(result) {
    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
    browser.getSession().then(function(session){
    var sessionID = session.getId()
    var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    var dataString = `{"name":"${result.fullName}"}`;
    var options = {
    url: 'https://api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/' + sessionID + '.json',
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString,
    auth: {
    'user': browserstackUser,
    'pass': browserstackKey
    }
    };
    function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);

}
}
request(options, callback);
});
});
}
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I tried this but it still shows baseUrl as the test name in browserstack instead of the test name. I am not sure what is the wrongdoing from my side.